# Primevue Multiselct selected value submitted as object

Tags: vue.js, primevue

I have the following value for a multi select in Primevue:

```
<script setup>

import MultiSelect from 'primevue/multiselect';

const conditions =  [
    { name: "Hyper Tension", value: "Hyper Tension" }
]

const form = reactive({
     conditions: null,
})
</script>
<template>
 <MultiSelect v-model="form.conditions" :options="conditions" optionLabel="name" placeholder="Select" />
</template>
```

Now when I submit the form, it is posting the complete object instead of the selected value. In the post body, I get :

```
"conditions": [
        {
            "name": "Hyper Tension",
            "value": "Hyper Tension"
        }
    ]
```

I only needs the value to be submitted. Also in the edit option, I would like to preselect the option, which is selected. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value in mounted hook and use `option-value` property to select just the value:

```js
const { createApp, ref, onMounted } = Vue;
const App = {
  setup() {
    const conditions =  [
      { name: "Hyper Tension", value: "Hyper Tension" }, { name: "Hyper Tension2", value: "Hyper Tension2" }, { name: "Hyper Tension3", value: "Hyper Tension3" }
    ]
    const form = ref([])
    onMounted(() => {
      form.value.push('Hyper Tension2')
    })
    return {
      form, conditions
    };
  },
  components: {
    "p-multiselect": primevue.multiselect
  }
};
createApp(App).use(primevue.config.default).mount("#app");
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/resources/primevue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/primeflex@^3/primeflex.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/primeicons/primeicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/core/core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/multiselect/multiselect.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
{{ form }}
<br>
 <p-multiselect v-model="form" :options="conditions" option-label="name" option-value="value" placeholder="Select"></p-multiselect>
</div>
```

Comment: But again in submit, it is submitting the whole object